# How to automatically dismiss alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating an android app in which I load a large data into local database asynchronously. On starting of that asynchronous task, I can show an alert dialogue. But the problem is that I can't dismiss it after completion of that asynchronous task. I am setting some flags to true after data load. So how can I dismiss the alert dialogue without user intervention by checking those flags?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is that, the asynchronous task is written in another class file. How can I dismiss the dialog  from that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ProgressDialog object global in your activity class like

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
```

Then create your dialog

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mProgressDialog .setMessage("Please wait...");
mProgressDialog .setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
mProgressDialog .setCancelable(false);
```

And pass the mProgressDialog to your AsyncTask class's constructor like

```
new MyAsyncTask(mProgressDialog)
```

This is your MyAsyncTask constructor

```
public MyAsyncTask(ProgressDialog prgDialog) {
    mPrgDialog = prgDialog;
}
```

Now you can use mPrgDialog object to cancel dialog. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

called `dialog.dismiss();`  in `AsyncTask onPostExecute();`

Answer (score 0):

In `onPostExecute method` of your asynctask `dismiss the dialog` using method `dialog.dismiss()`